# Problem in localhost - Next run dev - Development SERVER

Tags: node.js, localhost, next.js13

When I run `yarn run dev`
the result is :

```
- ready started server on [::]:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
- info Using wasm build of next-swc
Done in 37.09s.
```

But there's nothing " This site can’t be reached "

I tried To use `npm run build`  But that didn't solve my problem

when I run build it output this in the teriminal :

```
- info Creating an optimized production build ../c/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/npm: line 44:   535 Segmentation fault      "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.